# how do I increase the height of my container such that it fits the entire viewport of my screen? I'm very new to bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-7 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center p-0">
     <h1>x.</h1>
     <div class="col-lg-5">
      <ol><p>x.</p></ol>
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-xs-5 p-0">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/96/18/6b/96186b308addc3c4700a26adb3aac278.gif" class="img-fluid " alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[This picture shows my current view.  I'd like both columns to reach the end of the viewport instead of cutting out like it is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lyKe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap utility classes to achieve this. i.e `vh-100` and `h-100`

Set the container to 100vh and row to 100%.

**Note:** You'll have to adjust the image to fit the entire viewport.

```
<div class="container-fluid vh-100">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-7 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center p-0">
     <h1>x.</h1>
     <div class="col-lg-5">
      <ol><p>x.</p></ol>
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-xs-5 p-0">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/96/18/6b/96186b308addc3c4700a26adb3aac278.gif" class="img-fluid " alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```